# jQuery show sections having specific classes with buttons of same class or sub-class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have five paragraphs with some specific class name.

```
<p class ='biology_biotech'>1 Biology Biotech</p>
<p class ='biology'>2 Biology</p>
<p class ='biotech'>3 Biotech</p>
<p class ='physics'>4 Physics</p>
<p class ='chemistry'>5 Chemistry</p>
```

To toggle their visibility I have few buttons with same or similar class.

```
<input type = 'button' class ='physics' value = 'physics'/>
<input type = 'button' class ='chemistry' value = 'chemistry'/>
<input type = 'button' class ='biology' value = 'biology'/>
<input type = 'button' class ='biotech' value = 'biotech'/>
```

If I click button having specific class for example 'biology' I should be able to see all paragraphs which have the string 'biology' in their class-name ie para 1 & 2.
Likewise, para 1 & 3 if I click button having class biotech. and so forth.

However I am unable to get the desired result, I used indexOf and inArray. Following is my code.

```
$(function () {
    $("input").click(function() {
    var inpClass = $(this).attr("class");       
    var collection = $("p");
    collection.each(function() {
    var listClass = $(this).attr("class");
    var listItems = listClass.split("_");
    //console.log(inpClass);
    //console.log(listClass);
    //console.log(listItems);
    if(jQuery.inArray(inpClass, listItems) !== -1){
    collection.hide();
    $("."+listClass).fadeIn();
    }
    });
    });

});
```

Here is a [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/zihucarusi/edit?html,css,js,output) for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$("."+listClass).fadeIn();
```

to be

```
$('[class*='+listClass+']').fadeIn();
```

Comment: Since the showing/hiding process occurs inside `each`, the paragraphs won't fade in at the same time using this solution.

Comment: @Angel Politis. You are right about that. Having said that, the 'each' clause can be completely removed from the code.

Comment: now i get why it was slow. it hanged my browser few times.